# NullPointerException whlie changing startactivity

Tags: android

i want to change my start activity for actvity MainActivity to TuserActivity. i declared these line in my manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".TuserActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

But i got NullPointerException while running the application, how can i slove this problem?

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.krushi/com.example.krushi.TuserActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at com.example.krushi.TuserActivity.onCreate(TuserActivity.java:44)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)

TuserActivity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class TuserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private EditText tphnumber;
    Button btSend;
    TextView tEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tuser);

        tphnumber = findViewById(R.id.tphone);
        btSend = findViewById(R.id.btSend);
        btSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String mobile = tphnumber.getText().toString().trim();

                if(mobile.isEmpty() || mobile.length() < 10){
                    tphnumber.setError("Enter a valid mobile");
                    tphnumber.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(TuserActivity.this, VerifyPhoneActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("mobile", mobile);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        tEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(TuserActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

MainActivity:

```
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        public EditText emailId, passwd;
        Button btnSignUp;
        TextView signIn,txuser;
        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            emailId = findViewById(R.id.ETemail);
            passwd = findViewById(R.id.ETpassword);
            btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
            signIn = findViewById(R.id.TVSignIn);
            txuser = findViewById(R.id.tuser);
            btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String emailID = emailId.getText().toString();
                    String paswd = passwd.getText().toString();
                    if (emailID.isEmpty()) {
                        emailId.setError("Enter your E-mail");
                        emailId.requestFocus();
                    } else if (paswd.isEmpty()) {
                        passwd.setError("Enter your password");
                        passwd.requestFocus();
                    } else if (emailID.isEmpty() && paswd.isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fields Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (!(emailID.isEmpty() && paswd.isEmpty())) {
                        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailID, paswd).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Task task) {

                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                            "SignUp unsuccessful: " + task.getException().getMessage(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserActivity.class));
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent I = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_Login.class);
                    startActivity(I);
                }
            });
            txuser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent I = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TuserActivity.class);
                    startActivity(I);
                }
            });

        }
}
```

Comment: Check Mahendra Gohil answer.

Answer (score 1):

hey you missing the initiate tEmail textview
please add this to the TuserActivity.java before call tEmail.setOnClickListener()

```
tEmail = findViewById(R.id...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize **tEmail** before using it.

```
tEmail = findViewById(R.id.tEmail);
```

The final initializing block should be like

```
tphnumber = findViewById(R.id.tphone);
btSend = findViewById(R.id.btSend);
tEmail = findViewById(R.id.tEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

In TuserActivity, your code is failing at:

```
tEmail.setOnClickListener(...)
```

... because you never instantiated tEmail.

you need to find the view by calling :

```
tEmail  = findViewById(...);
```

Hope this helps.